# Images download using Goutte

Tags: php, cookies, curl, web-scraping, goutte

I have to download images using cookie in request. I could make it with file_get_contents (with stream_context_create) or curl with passing cookies. But how to make it with Goutte?

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
```

I make a GET request and what's the next step?

Ok, I figured that out:

```
$client->get('https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png', array('save_to' => __DIR__.'/image.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 2):

With Goutte 2:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_url' => 'https://www.google.pl',
    'defaults' => [
        'cookies' => true,
    ]
]);

$response = $client->post('/login', [
    'body' => [
        'login'    => $login,
        'password' => $password
    ]
]);

$response = $client->get('/images/srpr/logo11w.png');

$image = $response->getBody();
```

With Goutte 1 after adding "guzzle/plugin-cookie": "~3.1" to Composer:

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar;

$client = new Client('https://www.google.pl');

$client->addSubscriber(new CookiePlugin(new ArrayCookieJar()));

$response = $client->post('/login', '', array('login' => $login, 'password' => $password))->send();

$response = $client->get('/images/srpr/logo11w.png')->send();

$image = $response->getBody();
```